How does static resources help prevent security vulnerabilities?
If I want to use a third party utility library, it's advised to load it from Static resource into LWC/VF page instead of directly loading it in the LWC as per this guideline document
Is there anything that salesforce does to validate the content after a library/script is uploaded as static resource? If yes what kind of error/warning does it throw and where and how?
If not, and if the security vulnerability that the uploaded script might have has to be a responsibility of the developer, why to use static resource and not load it directly using :
<aura:component>
  <ltng:require afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.initializeUI}"
  scripts="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js”/>
<aura:component>


As per my understanding , static resources do not prevent security vulnerabilities. They just help to track the external libraries better for Salesforce security review team.
Static resources serve below purposes (summarised from the link shared in question):

It helps to associate the static resource i.e. 3rd party library with a managed package version & track changes in it.
It prevents the package code to be dependant on external endpoint thereby preventing unsafe & insecure code from being injected into the managed package.

Because of above reasons, directly using external scripts will attract review comments for managed packaged code.
Salesforce checks for the 3rd party library versions & its open vulnerabilities.
Example :
After a package is submitted for review, Salesforce will report vulnerability in static resource in below format :

In the above reported vulnerability, we had used insecure version of jQuery dataTable library which was fixed by upgrading it to the latest version and resubmitting package for review.
I would recommend to keep a watch on the vulnerabilities present in the 3rd party libraries used in managed package or in general & use the latest version.

Thanks I understand. What about non-ISV/non-packaged solutions where SF does not do a security review ? In such cases it shouldn't matter to use the libraries directly into code or through static resource ?

Yes, it will not matter for ISV/ Non-packaged solutions. But there will always be a security risk for the users of the application. What if the external endpoint is hacked and injects unintended script into component? I have experienced this in non-packaged code hence, recommending the use of best practices.

Yes I understand the best practice. The point I intend to make here is about the usage of static resources from security perspective. For ex, if a script has malicious code and we include it as a static resource and use it in non-packaged code (platform solution)  we are still at risk (as we would be if we used it by direct load). That is what I intended to understand and thanks for your answer.
